# CMD/WMIC redirection bug

Tags: cmd, windows-server-2003, freeze, io-redirection, wmic

I had a CMD batch file where WMIC would hang, depending on previous commands. I trimmed it down to the following:

```
ECHO.< NUL > NUL
WMIC /?
```

The same happens when using a different command instead of `ECHO.`, redirecting to or from other files than the `NUL` device or passing different arguments to `WMIC`. This is just the simplest way to reproduce the problem. Adding `/interactive:off` does not help. It also happens when typed directly into a `CMD` prompt (which stays 'broken').

It turns out `WMIC` **waits for user input** and does not continue until the user types <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a line of its own (or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
But only when the (any!) previous command had input *and* output redirected...!?
As a side effect a `TempWmicBatchFile.bat` file is created.

As a workaround `WMIC /? < NUL` solves the situation. This also creates a `TempWmicBatchFile.bat` file.

Previous lines should not influence `WMIC`'s behaviour! Or should they?

I found different people having this problem, but no explanation. Is this just a bug? In `CMD.EXE`? Or in the Win32 API?

All this happened in a virtual machine with Windows Server 2003 x64 SP2. My Windows 10 machine does work as expected.

Comment: must be a specific bug on a system, I tested this on a few of my systems now and get expected results each time including windows 7 and windows 8 x64

Comment: but then again, 2003 is pretty much not supported anymore, so why not upgrade? :)